# Default Landing Page For Facebook Application not working?

Tags: facebook, settings

The settings of facebook application give under: 
App settings>> Wall Settings>> Default Landing Tab for Everyone Else >>

provide an option to set the default landing page as wall.
But changing this setting is not working at all ..
i have checked for user who has liked and user who has not liked my application.

Is this a FB Bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Liking has nothing to do with it. That setting is for your app's Facebook page, not the app itself (i.e. canvas page). When a user comes to your app's page, that setting determine what "tab" is shown.

Comment: i had mentioned the thing about liking because i read in some forums that liking or not liking an app has some effect ...                  The original problem of the change settings not getting reflected still remains ..

Comment: Aah, right. The setting won't "stick" until you have a certain amount of fans/likes. I can't seem to find that number now.

Comment: it should be allowed for fan base of about 666K

Comment: sorry i think i wrote the answer less explicitly.. i mean to say that i have an app with 666k MAU and i was not able to change the default landing page ..